# Which open source software can calculate crystal diffraction diagrams?

Tags: linux, software-rec

Which open source software can calculate crystal diffraction diagrams for neutron and x-ray diffraction?

The software should finally create a picture like this by simulation:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Powder_diffraction#/media/File:Getit4.jpg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it clearly belongs to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Serge Please do not vote to close questions because they are also on-topic elsewhere. This question is on-topic here, so it should not be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Try http://vincefn.net/Fox/ - "FOX is a program for the ab initio structure determination from powder diffraction (neutrons, X-Ray)".  There are several others for xtallography processing and visualisation, that's just the first I could find (it's not my field of expertise but I used to do systems admin for a university chemistry faculty).  I suggest you also look at https://blends.debian.org/science/tasks/ and/or whatever similar pages your distro of choice may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Fox](http://vincefn.net/Fox/).

From the description:

> FOX is a program for the ab initio structure determination from powder
>   diffraction (neutrons, X-Ray).

There are several others for xtallography processing and visualisation, that's just the first I could find.

I highly recommend that you also look at the [Debian Science Blend](http://blends.debian.org/science/tasks) - lists of science and research related packages either already packaged for debian, in progress towards being packaged, and some not packaged for debian at all.  The Chemistry and Nanoscale Physics sections will probably be of most interest to you, but there's also a lot of useful software in other sections.

Other distros will also have similar science package pages which will be worth looking at. [Scientific Linux](https://www.scientificlinux.org/) in particular.